# jquery ui sortable disable if checkbox is not selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a sortable list with checkbox inside

HTML

```
<ul id="dynamic-fields-table" class="sortable-list">
    <li id="a1">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
            <span class="sort-drag-handler"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="a2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
            <span class="sort-drag-handler"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="a3">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 3</label>
            <span class="sort-drag-handler"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('.sortable-list').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable-list',
    placeholder: 'sortable-list-dropholder'
});
```

How can I disable the drag function if the checkbox is not checked?

FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/johndavemanuel/rmSgx/1829/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- disable all li items by adding "ui-state-default ui-state-disabled" classes to them

```
<li id="a1" class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">
```

2- exclude disabled items from sortable list

```
items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
```

3- add a function to handle checkbox state

```
   $('#dynamic-fields-table li input').click( function(){
  var item=$(this);
  if(item.is(':checked')){ item.parents('li').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
  }
  else {
   item.parents('li').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
  }


});
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/ercanpeker/Lutr8pe6/